# If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. How to solve this

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
app.module.ts

import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonPopupComponent } from './Shared/Common-popup/common-popup/common-popup.component';
import { PlantComponent } from './Masters/Plant/plant.component';
import DataTables from 'datatables.net';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-dt';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonSwalService } from './common-swal.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CommonPopupComponent,
    PlantComponent,
    NgModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,

    DataTablesModule,
  ],
  
  providers: [CommonSwalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'PlantWeb';
  constructor(private router: Router){}
  gotopage(any1: string):void{

  }
  // gotopage(pageName: string):void{
  //   this.router.navigate([`${pageName}`])
  // }
}
```

```
app.component.html
description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcC9R.png)
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Solve This

Comment: you need add a routes -the RouterModule is added as RouterModule.forRoot(routes)-. Generally you makes a module (usually called "AppRoutingModule") with the routes and is this module witch is added to your main.module, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route), but you can defined the routes in your main.module

Comment: Could you share the `AppRoutingModule`? I suspect you may not be exporting `RouterModule` from there (correctly). `NgModule` is also not needed in the declarations array, the decorators do work without it.

Answer (score -1):

first **NgModule** shouldn't it be in declarations list (this is most likely the source of the problem) instead NgM

second RouterModule should be called with forRoot/forChild([//routing config])

third since you import AppRoutingModule no need RouterModule again